# How is ElasticSearch queried using the Java client?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

The site only has documentation for JSON, but not the Java client. Is there some sort of mapping I should be performing?

For example geo location queries:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/geo-distance-range-filter.html

How would such a query be written using the Java client?

Thanks
Jason

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/client.html is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: It's close, but I still don't understand how to perform a Geo distance range filter query using the Java client. An example would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not obvious but not that complicated ;)

```
SearchRequestBuilder srb = client.prepareSearch(index);                
srb.setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
srb.setFilter(FilterBuilders.geoDistanceRangeFilter("filter1").lat(1234).lon(4321).geoDistance(GeoDistance.PLANE) ..... );
```