# Geo distance range filter in NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How can I apply a [geo distance range filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/geo-distance-range-filter/) using NEST? It seems to be something like

```
var results = client.Search<MyDataType>(s => s
.Filter(m => m.GeoDistance(c => c.Location, f => f.Distance(100, GeoUnit.mi)));
```

but how do I pass in long/lat of the target location?

(similar question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855635/how-is-elasticsearch-queried-using-the-java-client) for Java client)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question. This works:

```
var results = client.Search<MyDataType>(s => s
.Filter(m => m.GeoDistance(
  c => c.Location, 
  f => f.Distance("100 mi").Location(40.7, -74.0)));
```

After some debugging, I suspect that `f.Distance(100, GeoUnit.mi)` didn't work due to a bug in NEST.

Comment: Hey Max, mind logging this as an issue on github? https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/issues?state=open